# What's the meaning behind a coefficient of $x^r$ in case of $(1-x)^{-n}$? If we r not given any condition on x .

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Like suppose we have to find coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $[(1+x)^{3n+1}]\cdot (1-x)^{-2}$, why we assume the $|x|$ less than $1$ and expand that to get the coeffient, why not we divide that $(1+x)^{3n+1}$ polynomial from $(1-x)^2$ to get the resulting polynomial which will have a coefficient of $x^n$ in it ? Will this not work?

Comment: "divide that (1+x)^(3n+1) polynomial from (1-x)^2 to get the resulting polynomial".  The result is not a polynomial.  Also, "divide that ... polynomial **by** ... to get ...".

Comment: I see, so how one gets that coefficient (method) ? And why that method works ?

Comment: I edited it a bit more @Eric Towers

Comment: Like the reason is that if we have a number greater than 1 or less than -1, then the resulting summation would sum infinitely and diverge. For example $x^2$ with |x|>1 has $x<x^2$ meanwhile  if there was |x| <1, then $x>x^2$. Also, a side answer to your question is to use the binomial coefficient, your tag, to find the coefficient.

Comment: We just want coefficient which is left to ( )x^n , we r not concerned with what the nature of x isnt ?

Comment: And i am talking about (1-x) ^-2 not of x^2 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at
$$  \frac{(1+x)^{3n+1}}{(1-x)^{2}}  $$
for a moment.  This is a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function).  It is undefined at $x = 1$ (because division by zero is undefined).

The [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) allows us to replace $(1+x)^{3n+1}$ with
\begin{align*}  (1+x)^{3n+1} &= \sum_{k=0}^{3n+1} \binom{3n+1}{k} x^k  \\
&= 1 + (3n+1)x + \frac{3}{2}n(3n+1)x^2 + \cdots
\end{align*}
and (using [Newton's form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem)) also
$(1-x)^{-2}$ with
\begin{align*}
(1-x)^{-2} &= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{-2}{j} x^j  \\
&= 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \cdots  \text{.}
\end{align*}

The first series converges for all $x$ for any choice of $n$.  In fact, the first series is just a polynomial of degree $3n+1$.  The second series, expanded around $x = 0$, has radius of convergence $1$, since the asymptote at $x = 1$ is the closest singularity of the function (in the complex plane).  Consequently, for that series to be valid, $|x| < 1$.

If we want the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in the product of these two series, we can truncate each series to degree $50$ (because higher degree terms will not reduce their degree when multiplied by terms in the other series) and perform the multiplication.  The first few terms are
$$  (1 + (3n+1)x + \frac{3}{2}n(3n+1)x^2 + \cdots) \cdot (1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \cdots) = 1 + (3n+3)x + \frac{9n^2 + 15n + 10}{2}x^2 + \cdots \text{.}  $$
Continuing to degree $50$, we get a coefficient of $x^{50}$ that is a degree $50$ polynomial in $n$.  Note that one series is only valid for $|x| < 1$, so this product is only valid for $|x| < 1$, so this coefficient is only valid for $|x| < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to assume $|x| < 1$ since you can treat the expressions as "formal" power series in $x$.

At any rate, by the (extended) binomial theorem,
$$
(1+x)^{3n+1} = \sum_{k\geq 0}{\binom{3n+1}{k}}x^k \\
(1-x)^{-2} = \sum_{j\geq 0}{jx^j}
$$
then the coefficient of $x^n$ is
$$
[x^n] \left( (1-x)^{-2}(1+x)^{3n+1} \right) = \sum_{j+k = n} j\binom{3n+1}{k} \\
= \sum_{k} (n-k)\binom{3n+1}{k} 
$$
That sum can be broken into two terms, the first is just the constant $n$ times the sum of binomial coeffcients $\binom{3n+1}{k}$ and the second is a sum of
$kbinom{3n+1}{k}$.  Neither of these is trivial, as both are partial sums of binomial coefficients.  I suspect, however, that a closed-form answer exists in terms of Bernoulli numbers.